# Why does a plane fly like this?

Tags: flightradar24, flight-path

Why does a plane fly like this? 
[image: Track of plane flying all over the place]

https://www.flightradar24.com/LED5/dea0776

Comment: closely related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/30443/1467

Comment: Thanks @Federico. It could look like some surveying - but I'm kind of confused since a lot of the traffic is above a small local airfield. Is the plane circling while waiting for the airstrip?

Comment: That's definitely not an holding pattern.

Comment: I checked flightradar because it sounds like a helicopter has been flying around the vicinity for a while. I am not sure if LED5 is a helicopter though. Is there any way to find out exactly what kind of aircraft tih is? It doesn't seem to go very fast.

Comment: Could be related: [Blom Geomatics](https://imgrum.me/tag/BlomGeomatics). No more than a guess. [Corporate site](http://www.blomasa.com/main-menu/products-services/aerial-survey.html). Nice view from cockpit of [LN-NAB](https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/19420386_1619890228030483_1332078193281768477_n.jpg?oh=c1aada94af6c07c400048726bb5bb6a9&oe=59D43973).