# Why would an airplane fly in parallel, straight, closely spaced lines?

Tags: online-tracking, flight-tracking

I am not an expert with this kind of stuff and I seek an expert explanation.
Is this pattern related to a ground scan?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/30443/1467

Comment: Hello, welcome to Aviation.SE. maybe you have seen the above mentioned posts. Maybe you did not. It would be very helpful if you could explain, why these posts do not answer your question. Have fun!

Comment: Possibly [N338MM (Tenax Aerospace)](https://twitter.com/ItaMilRadar/status/959427192374595585).