# What is this aircraft doing?

Tags: flight-path, flightradar24

I spotted this aircraft on FlightRadar24 flying a strange route. What is it doing?

[image: Flight track FlightRadar24]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why did this aircraft fly in this pattern over Southern Italy?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/30443/why-did-this-aircraft-fly-in-this-pattern-over-southern-italy)

Comment: Looks like it's flying to me.

Answer (score 2):

http://bioflight.dk/ says they do "digital surveys" and "visual surveys."  The precisely parallel and equally spaced passes better visible [here](https://www.radarbox.com/data/flights/BIO02) suggest the former (camera images, stitched together after landing), not the latter (a human observer).